# Cannot create a cdo instance in python

Tags: python, cdo-climate

My python version is 3.10.6. I want to create an instance of a Cdo object in python (https://pypi.org/project/cdo/).

```
from cdo import *
cdo = Cdo()
```

Howerver, I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.10 /home/iliamous/PycharmProjects/winbank-esg-risk-gis-platform/scratch_work.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iliamous/PycharmProjects/winbank-esg-risk-gis-platform/scratch_work.py", line 209, in <module>
    cdo = Cdo()
  File "/home/iliamous/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cdo.py", line 190, in __init__
    self.operators         = self.__getOperators()
  File "/home/iliamous/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cdo.py", line 283, in __getOperators
    version = parse_version(getCdoVersion(self.CDO))
  File "/home/iliamous/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cdo.py", line 78, in getCdoVersion
    proc = subprocess.Popen([path2cdo, '-V'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1720, in _execute_child
    and os.path.dirname(executable)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py", line 152, in dirname
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: Have you installed the CDO binary, as noted in the requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there was an issue with the installation of the package. First, I removed the package by writing in the terminal

```
pip uninstall cdo
```

Then, I installed cdo again, this time using the command line

```
sudo apt-get -y install cdo
```

For more info check https://installati.one/ubuntu/20.04/cdo/.

Comment: Is this answer correct? You are uninstalling the python package cdo, but are then are installing the system library CDO, which are totally different things. Are you missing part of your answer?

Comment: This is what worked for me. I am not sure why...